# Arranging Django Queryset into a fancy DIV Layout (template)

Tags: django, templates, html, django-queryset

First of all I am a newbie to Django and trying to learn, so please tolerate my long question.

I have following django data models of my Application. To make clear I have edited and drop out most of the model.

```
class table1(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=40)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.user)

class table2(models.Model):

    accession = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    exp = models.ForeignKey(table1) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s, %s' %(self.accession,self.version)

class table3(models.Model):
    sf_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=False)
    mzml_fk = models.ForeignKey(table2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s' %(self.sf_id, self.name)


class table3_1(models.Model):
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sf_fk= models.ForeignKey(table3)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s' %(self.ref, self.value)


class table4(models.Model):
    soft_id = models.CharField(max_length= 45)
    version = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    soft_fk = models.ForeignKey(table2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s' %(self.soft_id, self.version)


class table4_1(models.Model):
    cvRef = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)
    soft_cv_fk = models.ForeignKey(table4)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s' %(self.cvRef, self.value)


class Selion(models.Model):
    monoiso = models.FloatField()
    state = models.CharField(max_length= 2)
    sele_fk = models.ForeignKey(table2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s' % (self.monoiso,self.state)

class trum(models.Model):
    spec_id = models.CharField(max_length= 60, blank=False)
    spec_index = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    spec_fk = models.ForeignKey(Selion)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s, %s, %s' % (self.spec_id,self.spec_index)
```

**Note**

- Selion is the most crucial model which contains till now more then 100500 records.
- I go through the deep of any records with the query of Selion (monoiso Decimal field)

**Case 1**

- To show all record of Selion my approach seems damn slow. It takes main page to load more then 10sec.

----In view-----

```
allsel = Selion.objects.all()
```

-----In template----

```
{{allsel|length}}
```

**Question**

- What's the most efficient way of showing the total number of Selion record in the main application template?

**Case 2**

- User input floating value in the search and do query on the database.
- I will find the inputted value range in Selion (monoiso field) and load result template.
- In result template on left DIV container I will show all the matched value in the lowest and highest range of Selion (monoiso filed)

---In View----

```
myquery = Selion.objects.select_related().filter(monoiso__range=(lowrange, highrange))
```

--- In template----

```
<div id="leftcontainer">
     {% for section in myquery %}
       <ul>                     
            <li><a href="#{{section.monoiso}}">{{section.monoiso}}</a></li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

I succeeded till now but couldn't progress further.

**Case 3 (above template)**

- Right DIV block is where all data models field are display.
- Right DIV block is horizontal tab, the first tab (Detail1) is for (table1, table2, table3, table4) and Detail2 for (trum)
- I want by default RQuery 1 to be active and show table1 data, scrolling will show table2, table3 & table4.
- If different links on left are click then content should change accordingly.

I am constantly trying to do it but couldn't figure out linking queryset into different tab and scrolling navigation. Moreover, I am having problem in performance when I have to filter out my above queryset.

Please help me to figure out the way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hydrate all of the "Selion" objects to get the length of the queryset. Instead use Selion.objects.count() which will return a scalar value instead of 100k+ objects.

For tabs, look into jQueryUI for a simple tab implementation with some Ajax callbacks to display the appropriate data in each tab.

Comment: @ Brandon- count() was perfect. I have already created the layout (left and right DIV). But, I am having problem in loading content in right DIV (tabs) after clicking links from left. If you have any tutorial regarding my problem can you forward me? Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about having the tab load content from a view via an Ajax call?

Comment: No I haven't thought about that, simply I was generating context variable and using them in template.

Comment: You can do either. Just depends on what's right for your app.